# Multiple subjects and subscriptions or only one - Angular 5

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular5

right now i'm coding the front-end for my application. Right now i have a service called socketio, which receives the data my app needs to display. Also, this service uses Subjects to pass the data to components through subsscriptions.

Is it better to have only 1 subject/subscription, which indicates what it is for inside the message, or have multiple subjects/subscriptions, one for each task?

I'm interested in the best approach regarding memory usage and process time.

Here's what my service looks like:

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable()
export class SocketioService {
  namespace = '/test';
  socket: any;

  positionsUpdate: Subject<object> = new Subject<object>();  // One subject
  pingsUpdate: Subject<object> = new Subject<object>();  // Another subject

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(location.protocol + '//' + 'localhost' + ':5000' +  this.namespace);

    const self = this;

    this.socket.on('advisor_ping', function(msg) {
      self.pingsUpdate.next(msg);
    });

    this.socket.on('advisor_position', function(msg) {
      self.positionsUpdate.next(msg);
    });
  }

}
```

Right now, if i take the multiple subjects approach, i would end up having like 9.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always want to have as few subscriptions as possible because otherwise it's easy to forget about unsubscribing, etc. You can also bind a single observable to the template via the async pipe, and it'll display all the values.

So your code example looks quite good

Also check out this article from Ben Lesh (manager of rxjs): https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87